# What does mean : "Describe the structure of $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times $ as commutative group?

Tags: group-theory

What does mean : "Describe the structure of $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times $ as commutative group ?

Comment: What do you know about this object?  Can you describe its elements?  Maybe give some more context and share your ideas to get a better reaction.

Comment: I take it you have talked about Chinese remainder theorem and the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem,

$\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}\equiv (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})$

We want to look at the multiplicative structure on this ring, so we have

$(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\equiv (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\equiv C_2\times C_6$

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer can be about an explicit description of its elements. In this case, this is not hard to do: let $d = (n,21)$ with $n \in [1,20]$. Now, by Bezout's identity, there exist integers $s,t$ such that

$$
nt+21s = d
$$

which modulo $21$ gives

$$
nt \equiv d \pmod{21}
$$

If $d = 1$, then $n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$. Reciprocally, if $n$ is a unit, that is $nk \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$ for some $k$, then it is coprime with $21$: if not, $n$ and $21$ would share some prime divisor, and looking at the previous inequality modulo that prime would be a contradiction.

So, to sum up, the units of $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ are exactly the integers which are coprime with $21$.

As you probably have noted, this argument uses no properties of $21$ whatsoever: in general,

$$
\mathcal{U}_n := (\mathbb{Z}_n)^{\times} = \{k \in [0,n-1] : (k:n) = 1\}
$$

Another argument can be made, noting that if $S,R$ are rings, then $(R \times S)^{\times} \simeq R^{\times} \times S^{\times}$. By the chinese remainder theorem, we know that $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/7\cdot3\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ and so

$$
(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \simeq \mathcal{U}_7 \times \mathcal{U}_3
$$

Since $\mathcal{U}_3$ has two elements, $\mathcal{U}_3 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. As for $\mathcal{U}_7$, it has order six, and so there are only two options, either $\mathbb{D}_3$ or $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Since the group is abelian, it's the latter, and thus

$$
(\mathbb{Z}_{21})^{\times} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z_6} \stackrel{CRT}\simeq 
\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z_2} \oplus \mathbb{Z_3}$$

Answer (score 1):

It probably means to give one of the [canonical decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification) for this abelian group: the primary decomposition or the invariant factor decomposition. Both follow from the Chinese remainder theorem in this simple case.